# Dúvida com Try Catch

Tags: c#

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
try
{
modelOn.pacienteOns.Add(Conversao.pacienteToOn(oObjeto));
oObjeto.online = 1;
modelOn.SaveChanges();
modelOff.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception i)
{
MessageBox.Show("----------------->>> " + i);
}
```

Preciso que o sistema execute os dois comandos `modelOn.SaveChanges()` e `modelOff.SaveChanges()`, caso não execute um, não deve executar o outro.

Minha dúvida é: Já que incluí ambos os códigos dentro do `try`, sempre serão executados os dois ou tem risco de executar apenas um?

Comment: Se alguma das linhas acima deles estourar uma exceção, corre o risco é de nenhum dos dois ser executado. Exceção interrompe a execução e pula direto pro catch.

Comment: isso mesmo que eu quero. ou os dois ou nenhum. você me confirma se é assim mesmo?

Comment: O raciocinio é o mesmo, e com esse código não tem como garantir isso nao. Se `modelOff.SaveChanges();` lançar exceção por algum motivo, o código do try é interrompido, mas `modelOn.SaveChanges();` já terá executado.

Comment: existe uma outra forma de fazer? pra executar todos ou nenhum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui esse código no suporte da DevMedia:

```
var bancoOnTx = bancoOn.Database.BeginTransaction();
var bancoOffTx = bancoOff.Database.BeginTransaction();
try{
    //faz as transações
    bancoOn.SaveChanges(); 
    bancoOff.SaveChanges();
    bancoOnTx.Commit(); 
    bancoOffTx.Commit(); 
} 
catch (Exception e){ 
    bancoOnTx.Rollback();
    bancoOffTx.Rollback();
    MessageBox.Show(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O `try` `catch` pode ser visto <del>como uma proteção contra 'crash'</del> para tratar erros de exceção de uma forma segura. O programa tenta executar o que está no bloco `try` e se encontrar um erro de exceção, salta para o bloco `catch`. Não havendo erros, pula o bloco `catch`.

O que você quer (executar um comando condicionalmente) não tem nada a ver com esta estrutura (que é proteção contra erro e não execução condicional).

Para que faça o que voce quer, concentre-se no bloco e ponha o condicional dentro dele.

```
{
 modelOn.pacienteOns.Add(Conversao.pacienteToOn(oObjeto));
 oObjeto.online = 1;
 modelOn.SaveChanges();
 modelOff.SaveChanges();
}
```

Como não sabemos o que os métodos retornam (se é que retornam algum valor), vou propor um código pra voce usar de exemplo:

```
{
 modelOn.pacienteOns.Add(Conversao.pacienteToOn(oObjeto));
 oObjeto.online = 1;
 if (modelOn.SaveChanges()) modelOff.SaveChanges();
}
```

Neste código, estou presumindo que o o método `SaveChanges()` de `modelOn` retorna `true` se salvou e `false` se não salvou. Desta forma o método `SaveChanges()` de `modelOn` só é executado se o outro tiver executado com sucesso.

Comment: E se `modelOff.SaveChanges()` não executar, sendo que `modelOff.SaveChanges()` já executou?

Comment: Além do que o diegofm já disse, a última coisa que um `try-catch` deve ser visto é como uma forma de evitar *crash*. Por causa desta visão as pessoas usam exceções do jeito errado o tempo todo. Justamente por  cauda disto as pessoas acham que fazer um `catch (Exception)` é uma boa coisa, elas acham que fazendo isso qualquer problema que a aplicação tenha será resolvido, quando costuma ser o oposto que ocorre. Quando mais de 90% das pessoas acham que isto é o certo será improvável que isso será resolvido, a maioria continua ensinando errado os que querem aprender e ensinará outro errado também.

Comment: @diegofm, como eu não sei o que fazem os métodos `saveChanges()`, eu só quis responder sua pergunta, demonstrando que o `try-catch` não vai garantir esta execução condicional. Você terá de trabalhar a lógica dos métodos pra que sejam executados exclusivamente. Pode usar o conceito de transaction ou um callback

Comment: @bigown, concordo que o `try-catch` é abusado. Quem nunca quiz colocar todos os blocos dentro dele? Editado

Comment: O `saveChanges` faz parte do Entity Framework e produz operações em banco de dados. Tem `try-catch`, nem `if` resolverá isto. EU não sei exatamente qual é a melhor solução, mas certamente passa por usar o EF de uma forma específica para que toda operação seja transacional. Pode até ser que precise mudar o modelo ou fazer uma gambiarra (ou lógica alternativa como alguns preferirão chamar), mas aí estou só especulando. Alguém poderá dizer que este método não lança exceção, mas não há garantias que um método não lançara exceção indiretamente.

Comment: A dica pode ser boa, mas ainda não resolverá o problema de garantir que ambos métodos sejam executados sempre, como foi questionado pelo OP. Realmente é complicado sugerir algo apenas com as informações passadas.

Comment: os métodos servem pra gravar no banco de dados. pelo que li da conversa de vocês, não é tão fácil quanto parece kkk. mas obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Também não é difícil, mas você não deu muita informação. Não tenho experiência com C#, mas `try-catch` é uma estrutura comum a outras linguagens e claramente, não é a solução que você procura. Você pode melhorar a pergunta ou fazer uma nova pergunta, com mais dados, tomando cuidado para não perder o foco.